Why does Blender 4.3 Texture keeps Bleeding on my model?
How to fix Blender bleeding texturing problem when using the brush to texture the model?
I was trying to put some texture on the character shoes...
I even unwrap the the shoes but it's still the same issue...


Hello, please pack your image and share your file so that we can give a try

If you have geometry enough, try to go to sculpt mode and paint there with the painting brush. For that you don’t need to unwrap your model and you can add it later on as an attribute in shading.
In your case I am not sure if the problem might be your unwrapping which is not looking very optimal. If you could mark seems manually and unwrap manually, you will get less pieces and better unwrapping.
Hope it helps.

I tried all that,  marking seams, unwraping both Manually and Smart, but I'm still getting the same issue

So this is the Shoe model, try to paint on top of the shoe Tongue and then you will see the texture breaking Issue:  https://blend-exchange.com/b/jgSVMdQa

By "texture Breaking you mean the jaggy edges to the paint strokes? That is caused by having a low texel density and using a steep brush falloff. The texel density can be increased by scaling up the UV islands in the UV space and or increasing the size of the image that you are painting on. 2048² instead of 1024². You are using a custom brush falloff try using the standard Smooth falloff instead. In the following link I have applied solidify and subD modifiers and redone the uv's  and increased the Image size to 2048. Use Smooth falloff and see if this is any better



Imma try that out on and see

So with all the combination of (Literally Everything!).. You said,  including applying all the modifiers, Get more Polygon Counts for better Geometry when Texturing,  And this time using Smart UV Unwrap... It Finally Works!, now i can paint on the Model without the Textures breaking, being super jaggy, and falling out of place,  like how  was i supposed to just know all of that? ... Thanks for the Help Man!  Imma rest now

Before UV unwrapping your shoe model, in edit mode check that the X Y and Z scale are all at 1.000. If they are not then you need to Apply the scale. Ctrl + A > Apply > Scale

Mark UV seams as they would appear on real shoes.

A:  around the lower edges, separating the uppers from the soles.
B:  around the opening edges, separating uppers from inners.
C: a vertical seam at the back of the heel of the shoe, this will enable the uppers to open out flat in the 2D UV space without too much distortion.
D:  a vertical UV seam at the inners opening.


In Edit mode select and UV unwrap the shoe using the Angled Based method. In the Last Operator panel, (bottom left hand corner) make sure the margin value (space between UV islands) is large enough so that when painting the colour does not spread to a neighbouring UV island.

There is a lot of wasted areas in the UV space this can be reduced by scaling up and repositioning the UV islands.

Select Uppers and Inners UV islands.
Rotate them by 45°.
Scale up so they better fill the UV space.
Reposition them inside the UV space.
Select the Sole UV island and scale to fit the remaining space. Note, because it is less important visually, in the anim. below, the Sole UV island was scaled down to fit.


The UV's are now ready for painting on the shoe model:


I'll try this one more time

So i tried this method, it fixes some of the Issues with the texture breaking when painting on the model, but it is still breaking when i'm painting on other parts on the shoes

I think your going to need to share the shoe model so that we can take a closer look to see what's going on. If you would like to do that then pack your image into the blend file and add the .blend file to your original question using this link   https://blend-exchange.com/

Have you tried Increasing the Bleed distance of the brush when painting? This adds paint beyond the UV island borders which is very necessary when painting on part of the model that has its UV seams that are not perfectly aligned to either the U or V axis in the UV space. You will find this option under the Brush tools >Options menu. By default the value is set to 2 pixels which is usually ok but if it is less than this you may find "jaggies" in your paintwork along UV seams when painting on the model. If so try increasing the value to 2 or 4 pixels.

So here is the Shoe Model, try and paint on top of the shoe Tongue and you will the texture breaking issue: https://blend-exchange.com/b/jgSVMdQa

So with all the combination of (Literally Everything!).. You said, including applying all the modifiers, Get more Polygon Counts for better Geometry when Texturing, And this time using Smart UV Unwrap... It Finally Works!, now i can paint on the Model without the Textures breaking, being super jaggy, and falling out of place, like how was i supposed to just know all of that? ... Thanks for the Help Man!  Imma rest now
